# Grid elements does not stretch vertically

Tags: html, css

My grid-container class does not extend vertically, but does extend horizontally. Size is set in percentages. How can I make my grid cells stretch in both directions?

```css
    .container {
      width: 20rem;
      height: 20rem;
      margin: 0 1rem;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .grid-container{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the **width** and **height** to the grid cell to be **100%**. This will make the grid cell stretch out both vertically and horizontally

```
.container {
  width: 20rem;
  height: 20rem;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padding` instead of using `height` because the height define what exactly the height should be but the padding cause both `height` and `width` to expand depending on the inside items so, `padding` will affect both your `height` and `width` and you'll find that your grid-container grows bigger because of the padding and the solution for that is to reduce the value of the `padding` and `width`

---

```css
.container {
      width: 20rem;
      padding: 20rem;
      margin: 0 1rem;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .grid-container{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I'd seen that there is nowhere you'd set the grid-container's width or height and I guess it'll be better if you determine that